# Is there such function like IsCallable?

Tags: autohotkey

I'd like to have in AutoHotkey function named, for example `IsCallable`, that can tell me whether an object (or anything that can be stored in AHK variable) is callable.

A callable object includes:

- a normal function represented as a string.
- a function object by `Func("somefuncname")`.
- a BoundFunc Object.

The key point is, if `fnobj` is callable, then the user can write `%fnobj%(...)` to actually call something.

Clarify my idea with code below:

```
test_check_callable()
{
    fnstr := "fnhello"
    fnobjA := Func("fnhello")
    fnobjB := fnobjA.bind("0th")
    fnobjC := fnobjB

    %fnstr%()
    %fnobjA%("A1")
    %fnobjB%("B1")
    fnobjC.("C1", "C2")
    
    r1 := IsCallable(fnstr)   ; true
    r2 := IsCallable(fnobjA)  ; true
    r3 := IsCallable(fnobjB)  ; true
    r4 := IsCallable(fnobjC)  ; true

    e1 := IsCallable("NoSuch")        ; false
    e2 := IsCallable({key1:"value1"}) ; false
}

fnhello(args*)
{
    Dbgwin_Output("fnhello() parameters: " args.Length())
    
    for i,arg in args
    {
        Dbgwin_Output(Format("  param{} = {}", i, arg))
    }
}

IsCallable(pobj)
{
    ; How to implement this? IsFunc? IsObject?
}
```

I hope r1, r2, r3, r4 should all get `true`, and e1, e2 get `false`.

[image]

I'm using Autohotkey 1.1.36.2 .

PS: Dbgwin_Output() is implemented here: https://github.com/chjfth/AmHotkey/blob/master/libs/debugwin.ahk

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used AHKv2, you could make use of [HasMethod](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/HasMethod.htm). I'd recommend the usage of AHKv2, it's already at the RC3 stage.

Something like this should work pretty well to cover all basic use cases:

```
fnStr := "fnHello"
fnObjA := %fnStr%
fnObjB := fnobjA.bind("0th")
fnObjC := fnObjB

class HelloClass
{
    Call() => MsgBox("Hello")
}

fnClass := HelloClass()


class NotCallable
{

}

no1 := "NoSuch"
no2 := {key: "value"}
classNo := NotCallable()

MsgBox(
"`"fnHello`": " IsCallable("fnHello") "`n" ;support pure strings
"fnStr: " IsCallable(fnStr) "`n" ;support string objects
"fnObjA: " IsCallable(fnObjA) "`n" ;support user-defined function objects
"fnObjB: " IsCallable(fnObjB) "`n" ;support bound function objects
"fnObjC: " IsCallable(fnObjC) "`n" ;same as fnObjA
"`"MsgBox`": " IsCallable("MsgBox") "`n" ;support built-in functions as pure strings
"MsgBox: " IsCallable(MsgBox) "`n" ;support built-in functions
"fnClass: " IsCallable(fnClass) "`n`n" ;support user defined classes

"`"NoSuch`": " IsCallable("NoSuch") "`n"
"no1: " IsCallable(no1) "`n"
"no2: " IsCallable(no2) "`n"
"classNo: " IsCallable(classNo) "`n"
)

fnHello(param := "")
{
    MsgBox("hi " param)
}

IsCallable(inp)
{
    if (HasMethod(inp))
        return true

    try
    {
        inp := %inp%
    }
    catch
    {
        return false
    }
    return HasMethod(inp)
}
```

Result:

```
"fnHello": 1
fnStr: 1
fnObjA: 1
fnObjB: 1
fnObjC: 1
"MsgBox": 1
MsgBox: 1
fnClass: 1

"NoSuch": 0
no1: 0
no2: 0
classNo: 0
```